# Facebook comments for non facebook users

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am trying to implement facebook comments, i was wondering is it possible for non facebook users to comment without using the login providers facebook allows? for example commenting as a guest without logging in.

[image]

Comment: Nice mockup! You threw me for a minute there; I thought that was a real Facebook screen, and I was like "when did they start allowing folks to authenticate from those other sites...?!?!" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry But You Cannot!
Facebook like and comment on Facebook is only allowed only by Facebook allow.
More you can read here in [Facebook comment document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)